# Ubuntu Windows App Curl Command Stuck on 0 speed with all 4 bars of WiFi (Windows 11)

Tags: windows-10, windows-subsystem-for-linux, bug-reporting, curl

So, I'm trying to run the Ubuntu WSL, and I'm trying to download a very small file with the curl command. However, it just hangs on this:

[i'm not allowed to embed images yet so click this link pls](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9HYhl.png)

and then times out.
Does anybody know why this is happening and how to fix it? I just restarted my computer by the way.

COMPUTER:
-Acer Aspire 5
-16 GB of RAM
-Built in 2021
-OS = Windows 11

Tagged this post as Windows 10 because they didn't add Windows 11 yet ;)

Comment: can you ping anything from WSL? can you see the ping time?

Comment: are you by any chance using a VPN?

Answer (score 0):

I just figured it out... sorry. Turns out that I don't have the best WiFi even though it's 5G and I was sitting next to the router.

Comment: Good to hear you figured it out!  Just a heads-up that I'm voting to close the question since it won't be something that others can reproduce and probably won't be helpful to other users -- There's nothing wrong with that, and hopefully we'll see you around in the future here with other questions or answers.  Thanks!